# validation on weight in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

can i get validation on weight which can take decimal values and also integer.
suppose if i enter 60 it has to accept and if i enter 60.50 it has to accept (60.1..etc)
but not characters. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expression validator to constrain input.

Positive Decimal: `(^\d*\.?\d*[1-9]+\d*$)|(^[1-9]+\d*\.\d*$)`

[How To: Use Regular Expressions to Constrain Input in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998267.aspx)

Comment: ya i will look and inform you Aseem Gautam thank you for response

Answer (score 0):

you can use compare validator and use type double and operator data type check. it will work for you.

Comment: no i mean only not 60 it could be any thing it is not fixed weight

Comment: yes you can use compare validator to do so, just select the operator data type check and you will get the validation, just try it by your self

Answer (score 0):

Ok try number two since I misunderstood your question :)

Use a `RegularExpressionValidator` and use the following expression:

```
^\d+\.?\d*$
```

Seems to match any number with as many decimal places as you allow.

Comment: no sorry u not get my point weight is not fixed it could be anything.

Comment: No I don't get it, do you just want to make sure it is valid number?

Comment: No i am not matching if user enter any like integer or decimal it should accept not characters like 5.2 or 25.23 or 52 or acceptable not characters

Comment: i check u r regular expression but it is taking characters like i enter 5r it is accepting. but it is not only digits not characters

Comment: Your right I had a mistake when that I didn't escape the `.` I have updated my answer to reflect this.